# Is it possible to display two multi-dimensional arrays next to each other using a for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to output  multiple multi-dimension array in C++, and need a little help understanding on why and how for loops display output where they do. I would like my first multi-dimensional array to output and then to the right of that I would like to have my second mult-dimensional array output. 
I am able to get my second mult-dimensional array to output underneath the first, but not next to it without making everything look like a mess. Below is an example of how I would like my code to output.

```
first         second
12 34 23      34 56 67
32 77 56      34 54 56
```

Below is the code I have to output my first mult-dimensional array. Thanks for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;




int main()
{
int a[2] [3] = 
{
    { 16, 18, 23 },
    { 54, 91, 11 }
};

int b[2][3] =
{
        { 14, 52, 77 },
        { 16, 19, 59 }
};

for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
    {

        cout << a[row][column] << " ";

    }
    cout << endl;
}


_getch();
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using 3 for loops, one for the number of rows (which will surround the other two for loops) and then have the for loop of the first array's columns, and then output a few spaces, and then the third for loop for the second array's columns.

For example:

```
for(i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < num_cols_1; j++)
    {
        // print j'th element in i'th row of array 1
    }

    // print some spaces

    for(j = 0; j < num_cols_2; j++)
    {
        // print j'th element in i'th row of array 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give the 3 for loops a shot. Thanks!